# customize uibarbuttonitem without uiappearance

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibarbuttonitem, uiappearance

Is there a way to customize ALL uibarbuttonitems to have a background image without using UIApperance?  Unfortunately our codebase has some limitations and we're not able to use UIAppearance so I'm looking for an alternative.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I was able to do this by subclassing UIBarButtonItem and it works for most of my buttons...but I'm wondering specifically how to do it with default buttons like UITableView edit buttons and UINavigationController backbuttons.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also can make subclass like this. First i go to make subclass of UIBarButtonItem. My CustomBarButtonItem.h should be like this.

```
@interface CustomBarButtonItem : UIBarButtonItem

+ (CustomBarButtonItem *)sharedInstance;
- (UIBarButtonItem *)backButtonwithTarget:(id)target andAction:(SEL)action;


@end
```

then inside my CustomBarButtonItem.m should like this.

```
@implementation CustomBarButtonItem

static CustomBarButtonItem * _sharedInstance = nil;

+ (CustomBarButtonItem *)sharedInstance
{
    if (_sharedInstance != nil)
    {
        return _sharedInstance;
    }
    _sharedInstance = [[CustomBarButtonItem alloc] init];

    return _sharedInstance;
}

- (UIBarButtonItem *)backButtonwithTarget:(id)target andAction:(SEL)action
{
    UIImage *backImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back_btn_normal.png"];
    UIImage *backPressed = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back_btn_hilight.png"];
    UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [backButton addTarget:target action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [backButton setBackgroundImage:backImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backButton setBackgroundImage:backPressed forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    const CGFloat BarButtonOffset = 5.0f;
    [backButton setFrame:CGRectMake(BarButtonOffset, 0, backImage.size.width, backImage.size.height)];

    UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, backImage.size.width, backImage.size.height)];
    [containerView addSubview:backButton];

    UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:containerView];
    return item;
}
@end
```

Then where ever you want to make custom NavigationItem (Button in the NavigationBar) you can put the code below for me it custom.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[CustomBarButtonItem sharedInstance] backButtonwithTarget:self andAction:@selector(searchButtonTapped:)];
}
```

All of my code are working fine. Hopefully it will help you.

Comment: this is what I did...but this doesn't fix things like UINavigationController back buttons or UITableViewController default edit buttons.

Comment: You have to call this function like the code below inside your ViewController.
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[CustomBarButtonItem sharedInstance] checkinButtonwithTarget:self  andAction:@selector(revealMenu:)];

Comment: Call it inside the ViewController on what button?  I'm trying to customize the back button on a UINavigationController...

Comment: Now you can fixes both rightBarButtonItem and leftBarButtonItem to be ever you want.

Comment: Did you see my code? i'm make custom for navigationItem. That mean the  navigation controller button that you need to make custom.

Comment: Did you even try this before posting?...it doesn't work.  A back button is different than leftBarButtonItem

Comment: Sorry for confuse. I'm already edit my answer to make more understand for you. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this. just copied it out of my project.

```
   _leftBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[self imageButton]]
                                                          style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                         target:self
                                                         action:@selector(showLeftViewController)];

    [navController.navigationBar.topItem setLeftBarButtonItem:_leftBarButton];
```

Comment: So for every ViewController, I need to set its back button like this?

Comment: You can put it on singleton which can take image & title as parameter and call it from your every controller. I would do it. Unless there is a better way

Answer (score 0):

To do this: create category on **UINavigationBar** and override method **drawRect**

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomBackground)
 - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect { 
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"background"]; 
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}
@end
```

This code allows you to change background for all UINavigationBar in a project.